# Why did the Altair use 100-pin edge connectors?

Tags: history, s-100, altair-8800

The Altair 8800 was based on what came in later years (much to the displeasure of MITS) to be known as the S-100 bus, because it had 100 lines, because MITS found 100-pin edge connectors were available cheaply.

Why were 100-pin edge connectors available cheaply? What were they used for before then? Were they some kind of de facto industry standard, was there some particular machine that used a lot of them, or was it just a random one off event that someone happened to be liquidating a few crates of them?

Comment: `much to the displeasure of MITS` Now you've got me curious why.

Comment: @ssokolow Ed Roberts, founder of MITS, thought of the system as 'his' and was not pleased by the quick profusion of companies making add-in boards and clone computers; he saw their insistence on calling it the S-100 bus rather than the Altair bus, as adding insult to injury.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As Wikipedia says ([S-100 bus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S-100_bus)):

> "(Author) then looked for an inexpensive source of connectors, and he
> came across a supply of military surplus 100-pin edge connectors. The
> 100-pin bus was created by an anonymous draftsman, who selected the
> connector from a parts catalog and arbitrarily assigned signal names
> to groups of connector pins."

So the prime reason is "a military surplus". I guess they were used in some army projects in the '70s, like TTL-based mainframes, but I cannot find any evidence for such a claim, as the military computers are not wide-known.

Comment: In the late 1970s I worked for a So, Calif. based aerospace company and they had a "surplus sales" store on-site.  At one point boxes full of 1000s of these 100 pin "S-100" connectors came into the store.  As I recall they were quite popular as homebrew was a thing at that point in time.  I do also recall seeing them in various pieces of test equipment that were built by the company.  I get the impression that these were just generally useful connectors.

Comment: Computers wouldn't be the only, or likely primary, use of these 100-pin connectors.  They would've been used in all sort of electronic devices.

Comment: It's still somewhat common to find that overall type of connector (coarse-pitch edge connectors, often with wire wrap or solder eyelet  termination) show up in surplus stocks.